# How to use DISP=SHR on an fopen

Tags: fopen, mainframe, zos

With code like:

```
fopen("DD:LOGLIBY(L1234567)", "w");
```

and JCL like:

```
//LOGTEST  EXEC PGM=LOGTEST
//LOGLIBY  DD   DSN=MYUSER.LOG.LIBY,DISP=SHR
```

I can create PDS(E) members while at the same time browsing the PDS(E) to look at existing members, as expected with `DISP=SHR`.

If instead I code:

```
fopen("//'MYUSER.LOG.LIBY(L1234567)'", "w");
```

The fopen fails if I am browsing the PDS(E) at the time, or the browse of the PDS(E) fails while I have the file open. In other words there is no `DISP=SHR`. According to the `fopen()` documentation, `DISP=SHR` is the default when using file modes of "r" etc, but not "w".

How can I provide `DISP=SHR` in the second example?

Comment: I’m hoping I can find a better answer for you, but so far, I’ve been told you can’t, and you should put in an enhancement request.

Comment: Thank you @KevinMcKenzie I will do that. Do you know whether that should be an RFE on the C compiler, or on something from the "z Systems Software"" list, if so what?

Comment: fopen() is a C run time library functions, so an RFE should be on Language Environment.

Comment: RFE raised - see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=142817

Comment: @ValerieR - I did expect someone to answer with something referencing dynalloc() as I had seen that and wondered if that was what I should be using. When no-one did, I assumed I had misinterpreted the sparse manual details on what dynalloc() did. If you write that up as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities...

For anyone not familiar with the internal structure of partitioned datasets (that is, PDS or PDS/E), these datasets are logically divided into two parts: a "directory" having pointers to all the individual members, and a "data" area containing the actual records for the individual members:

```
PDS: <DIRECTORY BLOCKS>
        <MEMBER1>: ADDRESS OF DATA FOR MEMBER1 (xxx)
        <MEMBER2>: ADDRESS OF DATA FOR MEMBER2 (yyy)
         ...
        <DIRECTORY FREESPACE)
         ... 
     <EOF - END OF THE PDS DIRECTORY>

     <DATA PORTION>
     +xxx = DATA FOR MEMBER1
            ...
            <EOF - END OF MEMBER1>
     +yyy = DATA FOR MEMBER2
            ...
            <EOF - END OF MEMBER2>
     ...
     FREE SPACE (ALLOCATED, BUT UNUSED)
     ...
     END OF PDS
```

Throughout the next few paragraphs, keep in mind that you can open either the entire PDS/PDSE, and this enables you to read/write whatever members you like, or you can allocate and open a single member, and that gets processed like any other sequential file.

First, if you actually to have a DD statement coded as you show in the question, then you may simply need to change your open from `fopen(dsn,...)` to `fopen(dd:ddname,...)`. If you're running under the UNIX Shell or you do something that results in your process running in a different address space (such as fork()), then this might not work, but it may be worth a try. If you do this with the JCL you show, the challenge would be managing the PDS/E directory - you'd need to issue your own "STOW" when you create/update a new member since the JCL allocates the entire dataset, not just a single member. The sequence would be:

1. Open the DD for output.
2. Write your data.
3. Update the PDS or PDS/E directory with new member information (this is where the STOW function comes in - it updates the directory of the PDS/PDSE to reflect the member you created or updated).
4. Close the file

If you also need to read members, you'd need to issue FIND (or BLDL/POINT - which can be fseek() in C) to point to the correct member, then read the member. I'm sure it sounds like a hassle, but the advantage of this approach is that you can allocate/open the file once, and process as many individual members as you like.

A second workaround might be to dynamically allocate the file yourself, and then open it using `DD:ddname` syntax...if you only infrequently access the file, this is probably easier to code. The gory details of dynamic allocation are fully described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.ieaa800/reqsvc.htm.

There are several ways to invoke dynamic allocation: you can write a small assembler program, you can use the z/OS UNIX Services BPXWDYN callable service, or you can use the C runtime "dynalloc()" or "svc99()" functions. The dynalloc() function is easy to use, but it only exposes a subset of what dynamic allocation can do...svc99() is more cumbersome to use, but it exposes more functionality.

However you do it, dynamic allocation takes "text units" that roughly correspond to the parameters you find on JCL DD statements. What you're describing sounds like you'd just need to pass DSN and DISP text units, and maybe DDNAME (you can either pass your own DDNAME, or let the system generate one for you).

The C runtime functions make all this easy, but be aware that there are a few oddities, such as the need to pad the parameters to their maximum length. For example, a DSN needs to be 44 characters and padded on the right with blanks - not a C-style null-terminated string.

Here's a small code snippet as an example:

```
#include <dynit.h> 
. . .

int allocate(ddn, dsn, mem)
{
__dyn_t   ip;                    // Parameters to dynalloc()
 . . . 

 // Prepare the parameters to dynalloc()

 dyninit(&ip);                   // Initialize the parameters
 ip.__ddname     = ddn;          //  8-char blank-padded
 ip.__dsname     = dsn;          // 44-char blank-padded
 ip.__status     = __DISP_SHR;   // DISP=(SHR)
 ip.__normdisp   = __DISP_KEEP;  // DISP=(...,KEEP)
 ip.__misc_flags = __CLOSE;      // FREE=CLOSE
 if (*mem)                       // Optional PDS, PDS/E member 
     ip.__member = mem;          //  8-char blank-padded

 // Now we can call dynalloc()...

 if (dynalloc(&ip))              // 0: Success, else error 
 {
     // On error,  the errcode/infocode explain why - values 
     // are detailed in z/OS Authorized Services Reference

     printf("SVC99: Can't allocate %s - RC 0x%x, Info 0x%x\n", 
            dsn, ip.__errcode, ip.__infocode);
     return FALSE;
 }

 // If dynalloc works, you can open the file with fopen("DD:ddname",...)

}
```

Don't forget that when you're done with the file, you generally need to deallocate it. 
The code snippet above uses "FREE=CLOSE" - this means that when the file is closed, z/OS will automatically free the allocation...if you only open and process the dataset once, this is a convenient approach. If you need to repeatedly open and close the file, then you wouldn't use FREE=CLOSE, but instead call dynamic allocation a second time after you're done with your processing and want to free the file.

If you need to concurrently access multiple files, beware that you'll need to generate multiple unique DDNAMEs. You can either do this in your own code, or you can use the form of dynamic allocation that automatically builds and returns a usable DDNAME (of the form "SYSnnnnn").

Also, don't forget that updating a dataset under DISP=SHR can be dangerous in some situations, especially if the dataset involved can be a conventional PDS as well as a PDS/E. The big danger is that two applications open the dataset for output concurrently...both will write data into the same place, and the result will likely be a damaged PDS directory.

There are some other oddities in the UNIX Services environment, particularly if you use fork() or exec() and expect file handles to work in subprocesses since allocations are generally tied to a particular z/OS address space. Services like spawn() can let the child process run in the same address space, so this is one possibility.

Comment: What does `STOW` mean? N.B. The first paragraph of your answer is the working part of my question. The problem arises when you don't have a DD name from JCL, but just a fully qualified PDSE directory name.

Comment: Updated my answer with more information...adding/updating a PDS/PDSE member requires altering the directory to reflect the member you wrote, and STOW is the system service that does this. When allocating DSN(MEMBER), the system automatically does it for you at the price of allocating the file over and over again if you have lots of members to work with. I'm not aware of a STOW function in the C Runtime...it likely takes a few lines of assembler code if you go this way, so if you can get away with the dynamic allocation approach, it would probably take less code and no assembler.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't needed to use STOW - fopen of a member appears to do it all for you.